# Easiest Way to Receive Sleep Notice in C++ on Windows 7

Tags: c++, winapi, native, windows-7-x64, win64

I am writing an native c++ application that needs to do a quick bit of work if the Windows 7 system is put into sleep mode---otherwise it will unavoidably crash when the system wakes up.

What is the easiest way to register for a system  event (suspend) using native c++?

I really just want to do what [these guys do](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30089/Handling-OS-Events-in-Windows-XP-and-Vista) but I have an arbitrary class (not a gui) that I would like to have setup an event handler and get the PBT_APMSUSPEND event and I'm not sure the easiest way to do this.

Autoitscript [apparently](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/107115-trigger-before-standby-in-w7vista/) has a nice way where you can write

```
GUICreate("Event Receiver")
GUIRegisterMsg($WM_POWERBROADCAST,"MY_WM_CALLBACKFUNCTION")
```

and I was hoping to have something similarly easy.... without a full-on message pump setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply create a hidden window using `CreateWindow/Ex()` and have its window procedure callback process `WM_POWERBROADCAST` messages.  You don't need to create a GUI app in order to create windows.

Comment: True enough, but you've still created a GUI app. It's just one that doesn't have any visible windows!

Comment: A console app is not a GUI project, especiallt if it runs without a visual console, but it still has full access to the entire Win32 API and thus can create windows, so would you call that a GUI app? And don't forget, the API also has the ability to create message-only windows as well.